# How to limit FFmpeg bitrate while recording an RTSP stream with codec copy?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am trying to record a short video from an RTSP stream using FFmpeg. 
And I am facing the following problem: the video size is too large. 
Using the command `ffmpeg -i file.mp4`, I've come to the conclusion that this is due to the bitrate that I am receiving from the camera RTSP stream.

To reduce the video size, I want to limit the bitrate. 
I don't mind losing quality by doing this. 
So I am using the following `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i STREAM_URL -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1
  -vcodec copy
  -an //Suppress audio stream
  -b:v 1000k  //Establish 1000 kbps for bitrate
  -minrate 500k
  -maxrate 1500k
  -bufsize 1000k
  -f segment
  -segment_time 300
  -segment_format mkv
  output%03d.mkv
  -max_muxing_queue_size 2048 //To fix bug: Too many packets buffered for output stream
```

I am using the previous command to record the stream. 
With `-vcodec copy`, it doesn't limit the bitrate.

The RTSP stream is using H.264 video encoding.

Is it possible to limit the bitrate without having to re-encode the video?